# mysql, Date Entering as all 0's?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have the following code:

```
$radate = date('Y-d-m h:i:s');
echo $radate;
foreach($_POST['member'] as $member)
{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO attend (UserName, rDate) values('$member', '$radate')");
    mysql_query("UPDATE users set rAttend=(rAttend+1) where UserName='$member'");
}
mysql_query("INSERT INTO raids (rDate) value('$radate')");
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET rTotal=(rTotal+1)");

    mysql_close();
?>
```

At present the echo is printing: 
2011-14-08 09:47:17

But when I do a diagnostic like this:

```
$result_id = mysql_query('SELECT * from raids');
if($result_id)
    {
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_id))
    {
$results[] = $row;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
}
else
echo mysql_error();
```

I get this as an output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [raidID] => 1
        [rDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [raidID] => 2
        [rDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [raidID] => 3
        [rDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [raidID] => 4
        [rDate] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    )

)
```

So, in a more succinct fashion, what am I doing wrong when it comes to inserting the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's date format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, not `Y-d-m h:i:s` :)
It should work with `$radate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

BTW, don't forget to escape anything you put in a query:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO attend (UserName, rDate) values('" . mysql_real_escape_string($member). "', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($radate) . "')");
```

Comment: Thank you much.  For the record though, these values are both generated from the database itself and don't *really* need escaping, but I suppose that it can't hurt.  Thanks for that too.

Answer (score 1):

If that happens, you should query the warnings after the `INSERT`. Probably there is a warning pointing you out what was wrong.

EDIT: Now I got the mistake: you have the wrong date format. You should do `$radate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');` in order to get the correct `2011-08-14 19:01:30`. There is no 8th day in the 14th month, as there is no 14th month.
`

Besides, you are vulnerable to SQL injections as you take data from $_POST immediately into the database. Instead of

```
INSERT INTO attend (UserName, rDate) values('$member', '$radate')
```

you should do

```
INSERT INTO attend (UserName, rDate) values('" . mysql_real_escape($member). "', '$radate')
```

as this prevents a malicious user to set the `POST`ed value to `', ''); DELETE FROM attend; --`.